# Angular filter does not work

Tags: angularjs

I ran into this problem with an angular js project that was started with the angular-seed project.  Here's the code snip:

```
Search: <input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Type in a full text search">
<p ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
Showing {{searchText}}.
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:searchText">
    {{phone.name}} ha {{phone.snippet}}</li>
</ol>
</p>
```

The first search box works!  The second does NOT!  I don't get any errors to indicate what is wrong.

When I remove the `ng-controller="MyCtrl1"` markup, both search boxes work!  The tutorial, angular-phonecat, and angular-seed projects are a little different.  The seed project uses this kind of code to assign the controller to the view.

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]);
```

The phonecat project uses the `ng-controller="MyCtrl1"` markup.  Obviously I don't need to declare my controller twice, so it makes sense for me to remove it.

This fixes the problem, but why is this happening?

(Also I wanted to put this information into SO in case anyone else runs into this issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AngularJS, each controller creates a new scope. So you need to use `$parent` to access the model defined at the outer controller if you have nested controllers:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl1">Search:
    <input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Type in a full text search">
    <p ng-controller="MyCtrl1">Search:
        <input ng-model="$parent.searchText">Showing {{searchText}}.
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:searchText">{{phone.name}} ha {{phone.snippet}}</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting!  Thanks for helping an Angular.js newbie.  :)

Comment: Ah.  And I read today that you cannot have nested **apps**, but you can have nested **controllers** - accidentally in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-controller="MyCtrl1"` has own scope. According to [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angController) *The ngController directive assigns behavior to a scope. This is a key aspect of how angular supports the principles behind the Model-View-Controller design pattern.* And second, Angular has lazy binding nature, you will not see the error.

Comment: Funny.  Today I read the documentation for ngApp, and filter since I thought those were my problems.  Thanks!